# affect divs of a class inside one container div using jquery .parent() and other relatives

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a way to make the text inside divcontainer1 of class a bold, but I'm not entirely sure how to do this without affecting the div in container2, and affect both the inner and outer a. I'm sure this is possible with some parent().siblings().children().children-combination, but I'm not entirely sure how

Sample HTML

```
<divcontainer1>
  <div>
    <div class="a button">
      button
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="a">
        affect
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="a">
      affect
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="b">
      don't affect
    </div>
  </div>
</divcontainer1>
<divcontainer2>
  <div class="a">
    don't affect
  </div>
</divcontainer2>
```

Sample JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(/* make all text inside container 1 bold*/)
});
```

I tried parent().parent().children().children().css('font-weight', 'bold'), but that didn't seem to work

Comment: Have you tried to use ids to identify the containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.parents` to find the `divcontainer1` which contains the button. Then use `.find` to select the anchor elements within the container.

```js
$('.button').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('divcontainer1').find('.a').css('font-weight', 'bold'); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<divcontainer1>
  <div>
    <div class="a button">
      button
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="a">
        affect
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="a">
      affect
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="b">
      don't affect
    </div>
  </div>
</divcontainer1>
<divcontainer2>
  <div class="a">
    don't affect
  </div>
</divcontainer2>
```

*Note: It is not a good practice to use single letter class names. Also, it appears you may actually want to use the `button` and `a` elements instead of only `div`s.*

Answer (score 1):

```
$("divcontainer1").find(".a").css("font-weight", "700");
```

Comment: If you're doing this, you might as well do `$("divcontainer1 .a").css(...` - unless there's a good reason not... the explanation here is a listtle sparse

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to explain **why** it should work?

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate to the divcontainer using parent and then find the elements with the class 'a' to select just the elements in the div the button is contained in.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.a').css('font-weight', 'bold');
    });
});
```